# Random changes in a string of 0s and 1s

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

We have a string (sequence) of 0s and 1s, and at each step we randomly change a 0 to 1 or a 1 to 0.
On average, how many steps do we need to make to get back the original string?
How does this depend on the length of string?

For example:

```
01000101010110
```

I think the possible states can be modelled as a graph and the steps as some random walk along it.
The number of vertices will be $2^n$ where n is the length of the string.

Comment: I'd suggest you try with length 2 and 3 first, see if you can spot a pattern to exploit. Also, googling "random walk hypercube" led me to many promising results, like [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02359.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by each step? (A space-step from right to left or an iteration of the whole string) Actually it depends on the random number generator as well.

Comment: I  meant that randomly any one (but exactly one) of the digits is changed at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory of **finite-state discrete-time time-homogenous Markov chains** tells us that if we run the game for much more than $2^{n}$ steps, the probabilities to be in each state will converge towards a unique steady distribution. (This is not exactly true, but it *would* be true if in each step there was some probability, *however small*, of staying in the same state instead of flipping a bit -- if we want to be rigorous we can let this probability go to 0 at the end of the analysis). By symmetry this steady distribution must have a probability of $2^{-n}$ for each possible string.

So after $M\ggg 2^n$ steps we expect to have been in any given state $M/2^n$ times. (and the law of large numbers tells us that the *fraction* $1/2^n$ will become more and more precise with probability $1$).

This is especially true for the starting state, which means that at large $M$ we have been in the starting state $M/2^n$ times during $M$ steps -- which means that the *average time* that has passed between visits to the starting state is $2^n$.

But the process has no memory, so this long-term average will also be the *expected time* to the first return after we've started the game.

Comment: If you look only at every other step, and all states that differ from the original starting string at exactly an even number of places, then it _is_ exactly true. Half as many states, twice as many actual steps per Markov step, same final result.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, that works too. (I decided against it as the main explanation, because it seemed it would be harder to handwave my way around explaining periodicity then).